# how to nested boxplot groupBy

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset of more than 50 features that correspond to the specific movement during leg rehabilitation. I compare the group that used our rehabilitation device with the group recovering without using it. The group includes patients with 3 diagnoses and I want to compare boxplots of before (red boxplot) and after (blue boxplot) for each diagnosis.
This is the snippet I was using and the output I am getting.

Control group data:

```
dataKONTR 
           Row        DG  DKK  ...  LOS_DCL_LB  LOS_DCL_L  LOS_DCL_LF
0    Williams1    distorze  0.0  ...          63         57          78
1    Williams2    distorze  0.0  ...          91         68          67
2    Norton1           LCA  1.0  ...          58         90          64
3    Norton2           LCA  1.0  ...          29         91          87
4    Chavender1   distorze  1.0  ...          61         56          75
5    Chavender2   distorze  1.0  ...          54         74          80
6    Bendis1      distorze  1.0  ...          32         57          97
7    Bendis2      distorze  1.0  ...          55         69          79
8    Shawn1             AS  1.0  ...          15         74          75
9    Shawn2             AS  1.0  ...          67         86          79
10   Cichy1            LCA  0.0  ...          45         83          80
```

This is the snippet I was using and the output I am getting.

```
temp = "c:/Users/novos/ŠKOLA/Statistika/data Mariana/%s.xlsx"

dataKU = pd.read_excel(temp % "VestlabEXP_KU", engine = "openpyxl", skipfooter= 85)     # patients using our rehabilitation tool
dataKONTR = pd.read_excel(temp % "VestlabEXP_kontr", engine = "openpyxl", skipfooter=51)    # control group

dataKU_diag = dataKU.dropna()
dataKONTR_diag = dataKONTR.dropna()


dataKUBefore = dataKU_diag[dataKU_diag['Row'].str.contains("1")]        # Patients data ending with 1 are before rehab
dataKUAfter = dataKU_diag[dataKU_diag['Row'].str.contains("2")]         # Patients data ending with 2 are before rehab

dataKONTRBefore = dataKONTR_diagL[dataKONTR_diag['Row'].str.contains("1")]  
dataKONTRAfter = dataKONTR_diagL[dataKONTR_diag['Row'].str.contains("2")]

b1 = dataKUBefore.boxplot(column=list(dataKUBefore.filter(regex='LOS_RT')), by="DG", rot = 45, color=dict(boxes='r', whiskers='r', medians='r', caps='r'),layout=(2,4),return_type='axes')


plt.ylim(0.5, 1.5)
plt.suptitle("")
plt.suptitle("Before, KU")

b2 = dataKUAfter.boxplot(column=list(dataKUAfter.filter(regex='LOS_RT')), by="DG", rot = 45, color=dict(boxes='b', whiskers='b', medians='b', caps='b'),layout=(2,4),return_type='axes')
# dataKUPredP
plt.suptitle("")
plt.suptitle("After, KU")
plt.ylim(0.5, 1.5)
plt.show()
```

Output is in two figures (red boxplot is all the "before rehab" data and blue boxplot is all the "after rehab")

[image: Before rehabilitation]
[image: After rehabilitation]

Can you help me how make the red and blue boxplots next to each other for each diagnosis?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to concatenate the data into a single dataframe:

```
dataKUPlot = pd.concat({
    'Before': dataKUBefore,
    'After': dataKUAfter,
}, names=['When'])
```

You should see an additional index level named `When` in the output.
Using the example data you posted it looks like this:

```
>>> pd.concat({'Before': df, 'After': df}, names=['When'])
                 Row        DG  DKK  ...  LOS_DCL_LB  LOS_DCL_L  LOS_DCL_LF
When                                                                       
Before 0   Williams1  distorze  0.0  ...          63         57          78
       1   Williams2  distorze  0.0  ...          91         68          67
       2     Norton1       LCA  1.0  ...          58         90          64
       3     Norton2       LCA  1.0  ...          29         91          87
       4  Chavender1  distorze  1.0  ...          61         56          75
After  0   Williams1  distorze  0.0  ...          63         57          78
       1   Williams2  distorze  0.0  ...          91         68          67
       2     Norton1       LCA  1.0  ...          58         90          64
       3     Norton2       LCA  1.0  ...          29         91          87
       4  Chavender1  distorze  1.0  ...          61         56          75
```

Then you can plot all of the boxes with a single command and thus on the same plots, by modifying the `by` grouper:

```
dataKUAfter.boxplot(column=dataKUPlot.filter(regex='LOS_RT').columns.to_list(), by=['DG', 'When'], rot = 45, layout=(2,4), return_type='axes')
```

I believe that’s the only “simple” way, I’m afraid that looks a little confused:

[image: the pandas way]

Any other way implies manual plotting with matplotlib − and thus better control. For example iterate on all desired columns:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, sharey=True, sharex=True)
pos = 1 + np.arange(max(dataKUBefore['DG'].nunique(), dataKUAfter['DG'].nunique()))
redboxes = {f'{x}props': dict(color='r') for x in ['box', 'whisker', 'median', 'cap']}
blueboxes = {f'{x}props': dict(color='b') for x in ['box', 'whisker', 'median', 'cap']}

ax_it = axes.flat
for colname, ax in zip(dataKUBefore.filter(regex='LOS_RT').columns, ax_it):
    # Making a dataframe here to ensure the same ordering
    show = pd.DataFrame({
        'before': dataKUBefore[colname].groupby(dataKUBefore['DG']).agg(list),
        'after': dataKUAfter[colname].groupby(dataKUAfter['DG']).agg(list),
    })

    ax.boxplot(show['before'].values, positions=pos - .15, **redboxes)
    ax.boxplot(show['after'].values, positions=pos + .15, **blueboxes)

    ax.set_xticks(pos)
    ax.set_xticklabels(show.index, rotation=45) 
    ax.set_title(colname)
    ax.grid(axis='both')

# Hide remaining axes:
for ax in ax_it:
    ax.axis('off')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new column to separate 'Before' and 'After'.  Seaborn's `boxplot`s can use that new column as `hue`. `sns.catplot(kind='box', ...)` creates a grid of `boxplot`s:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

names = ['Adams', 'Arthur', 'Buchanan', 'Buren', 'Bush', 'Carter', 'Cleveland', 'Clinton', 'Coolidge', 'Eisenhower', 'Fillmore', 'Ford', 'Garfield', 'Grant', 'Harding', 'Harrison', 'Hayes', 'Hoover', 'Jackson', 'Jefferson', 'Johnson', 'Kennedy', 'Lincoln', 'Madison', 'McKinley', 'Monroe', 'Nixon', 'Obama', 'Pierce', 'Polk', 'Reagan', 'Roosevelt', 'Taft', 'Taylor', 'Truman', 'Trump', 'Tyler', 'Washington', 'Wilson']
rows = np.array([(name + '1', name + '2') for name in names]).flatten()
dataKONTR = pd.DataFrame({'Row': rows,
                          'DG': np.random.choice(['AS', 'Distorze', 'LCA'], len(rows)),
                          'LOS_RT_A': np.random.randint(15, 100, len(rows)),
                          'LOS_RT_B': np.random.randint(15, 100, len(rows)),
                          'LOS_RT_C': np.random.randint(15, 100, len(rows)),
                          'LOS_RT_D': np.random.randint(15, 100, len(rows)),
                          'LOS_RT_E': np.random.randint(15, 100, len(rows)),
                          'LOS_RT_F': np.random.randint(15, 100, len(rows))})
dataKONTR = dataKONTR.dropna()
dataKONTR['When'] = ['Before' if r[-1] == '1' else 'After' for r in dataKONTR['Row']]
cols = [c for c in dataKONTR.columns if 'LOS_RT' in c]

df_long = dataKONTR.melt(value_vars=cols, var_name='Which', value_name='Value', id_vars=['When', 'DG'])
g = sns.catplot(kind='box', data=df_long, x='DG', col='Which', col_wrap=3, y='Value', hue='When')
g.set_axis_labels('', '') # remove the x and y labels
```

[image: grid of grouped boxplots]